# Dynamic Fields ModelForms Django

Tags: python, django, forms, dynamic

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically change a ModelForm field based on the input from a previous field.

For example, if I have these kinds of models:

```
class Phone(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Series(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
     phone = models.ForeignKey('Phone') 
     series = models.ForeignKey('Series')     

class ManufacturerForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Manufacturer
```

Which would generate a form (ManufacturerForm) with dropdown options for the phone and series entries in the database. Is it possible to a different set of `series` entries based on the `phone` entered by the user, for example?

I have read about using the `__init__` method to accomplish this, based on what I have read on [this blog post](http://www.rossp.org/blog/2008/dec/15/modelforms/), but I am not sure how to execute this given my scenario. Or maybe there is a better way to go about achieving this that you have taken? Thanks for any advice!

---

EDIT: Added the form's view.

```
def make_ad(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ManufacturerForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            a = form.save()
            a.user = request.user
            a.save()
    else:
        form = ManufacturerForm()

    variables = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form
    })
    return render_to_response('place.html', variables)
```

@super9 mentioned using ajax request to change these elements. I need to check `if request.is_ajax()`, but at what point should I check this in my view? And how do I add or change the queryset based on the ajax request?

Thanks for your advice.

---

EDIT: Trying to use django-smart-selects

Not sure how to setup my models to utilize django-smart-selects to accomplish what I am trying. Here is how I have structured my models:

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey 

class Phone(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Series(models.Model):
    series = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(Phone)

class SeriesModel(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series)

class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    phone = models.ForeignKey(Phone)
    series = ChainedForeignKey (Series, chained_field = "phone", chained_model_field = "phone")
    series_model = ChainedForeignKey (SeriesModel, chained_field = "series", chained_model_field = "series")
```

But when I view my form (ModelForm) the fields for `series_model` are not chained properly to `series`. Am I missing something to make smart-selects work on the second layer of abstraction?

---

EDIT: Above code now works.

Comment: You will need to make an AJAX call to update the series selection based on what is selected in the phone.

Comment: Thanks for your response @super9. Do you have any advice for changing / adding a queryset using `request.is_ajax()`? Thanks for your ideas